# Is there any way to make custom AsynchronousTaskObjects?

Tags: asynchronous-processing

One of the pieces of functionality that intrigues me the most in Mathematica 9+ comes in the form of [`StartAsynchronousTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartAsynchronousTask.html) and friends. However, it can only start specific sorts of [`AsynchronousTaskObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsynchronousTaskObject.html)s, which are returned by a very small set of functions, including [`URLFetchAsynchronous`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLFetchAsynchronous.html) and [`DeviceExecuteAsynchronous`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeviceExecuteAsynchronous.html).

However, it seems like there are many other potentially interesting things one could do with such an approach, like submitting a parallel computation or making use of the new [`StartProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html) command if one were able to create one's own `AsynchronousTaskObject`. However, I don't see any way to do this, at least not in `` System` ``.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the interface for building them is not exposed in ``System` ``. The closest I could come is `CreateScheduledTask` which I've used from parallel kernels to implement a heartbeat monitor.